# Arbitrary paper size while scanning with OKI MB441

Tags: scanner, multi-function-printer

Is it possible to scan arbitrary paper sizes with OKI MB441? For example photographic pictures?

I see only poor predefined set of sizes:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this section from the manual about printing will also work for scanning.

Quoting from [page 52](http://www.manualslib.com/manual/410310/Oki-Mb441mfp.html?page=52), section "Printing on Custom Size Paper" :

> **For Windows PCL Printer Driver**
>
> 1. Click **Start** and select **Devices and Printers**.
> 2. Right-click the OKI MB491 icon and select **Printing preferences > OKI MB491(PCL)**.
> 3. On the Setup tab, click **Paper Feed Options**.
> 4. Click **Custom Size**.
> 5. Enter a name and the dimensions.
>
>    - Enter a name for the new size in the **Name** box.
>    - Enter its dimensions in the **Width** and **Length** boxes.
> 6. Click **Add** to save the custom paper size to the list and then click **OK**.
>      You can save up to 32 custom sizes.
> 7. Press **OK** until the Printing Preferences dialog box is closed.
> 8. Open the file you want to print.
> 9. Select the registered paper size and start printing on the print dialog.

If that doesn't work, ensure that you have the [latest driver](http://www.okiprintingsolutions.com/support/printer/printer-drivers/results.aspx?prodid=tcm:138-131640&search=2).

Comment: Scanning occurs by scanner writing files onto SMB share, so no any PC drivers involved.

Comment: The driver is involved for an OKI MB441 scanner. Please try the above procedure.

Comment: I have tried and can say, that adding custom sizes into printer driver on a client computer does not transfer to the MFD OS and does not seen in either web-interface or MFD LCD screen (which would be miracle).

Comment: A miracle or better software design. Sorry, but I can't find a better idea.